# Ajax Is not working when layout is set in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 and i am trying to use AJAX dialog in my view and load a partial view in it.
But when i set the layout to    "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; the ajax does not work while if i set it to NULL the ajax works. Kindly tell me where i am doing wrong

```
ViewBag.Title = "editSurvey";
Layout = null;
}

<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Edit Questions</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/minified/jquery-ui.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $("#openDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr('href');

            $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Add Student',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 355,
                width: 400,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(url);
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $(".editDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog({
                title: 'Edit Customer',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 355,
                width: 400,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(url);

                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $(".confirmDialog").live("click", function (e) {

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 170,
                width: 350,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                buttons: {
                    "OK": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        window.location = url;

                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                }
            });
            $("#dialog-confirm").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $(".viewDialog").live("click", function (e) {
            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#dialog-view").dialog({
                title: 'View Customer',
                autoOpen: false,
                resizable: false,
                height: 355,
                width: 400,
                show: { effect: 'drop', direction: "up" },
                modal: true,
                draggable: true,
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).load(url);

                },
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                },
                close: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            });

            $("#dialog-view").dialog('open');
            return false;
        });

        $("#btncancel").live("click", function (e) {
            $("#dialog-edit").dialog('close');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A partial view should only contain a snippet of html markup that will be included within the layout markup once rendered to the browser. Partials shouldn't contain the `html`, `head`, etc tags as they are defined in the layout. If you look at the source of the page once you set the layout, you probably see the `html` tag that you've included in your partial and everything within it embedded within the markup of your layout. The browser won't be able to load the script files.

The solution is to move your jquery scripts into the layout file rather than the partial and strip out the `html` and `head` tags from the partial view.

Comment: I have found its solution there was a line in the end of the layout file 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
i simply deleted it and my AJAX is working now.... And as you said i removed the HTML tags and Moved Script in to the head file.. But i am wondring why this is happaning only if you can explain me. This line was the main cause.